# ¿cómo escribir exactamente i veces truco[i], i variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sé como escribir varias veces una cadena, pero no cuando hay una variable dentro

Entonces : **¿cómo escribir exactamente i veces truco[i], i variable?**

**Ejemplo :**

Tengo una serie de caracteres `elegido` de tamaño tres. No sé exactamente qué contiene, pero cuando hay `---` en la posición `i`, quiero escribir exactamente i-1 una vez `elegido [i]` en una variable de almacenamiento, `i` esta una variable.

#### Rendimiento esperado

El ambito esta acceder a la buena dataframe df.loc[sections]. Por ejemplo si no hay `---`, en ninguno de  seria :

```
elegidos = elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2],elegido[3]
```

Para obtener :

```
df.loc[elegidos] # = df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2],elegido[3]]
```

Al contrario si habia uno en `elegido[3]` seria :

```
elegidos = elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2]
```

Para obtener :

```
df.loc[elegidos] # = df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2]]
```

**Lo que intenté y que funciona :**

```
if elegido[1] == "---":
    # on doit avoir i-1 fois elegido[i] dans le print(df.loc[])
    df_query = df.loc[elegido[0]]
    print("You selected :\n",df.loc[elegido[0]])
elif elegido[2] == "---":
    df_query = df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1]]
    print("You selected :\n",df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1]])
elif elegido[3] == "---":
    df_query = df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2]]
    print("You selected :\n",df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2]])
else:
    df_query = df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2],elegido[3]]
    print("You selected :\n", df.loc[elegido[0],elegido[1],elegido[2],elegido[3]])
```

Pero no es generalizable

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien el problema es básicamente obtener los elementos de un iterable hasta que se encuentra un determinado valor ("---" en este caso) o el iterable al completo si no se encuentra.

Por ejemplo, para:

```
elegido = ["aaa", "bbb", "---", "ddd"]
```

quieres obtener:

```
elegidos = ["aaa", "bbb"]
```

En este caso tienes varias opciones:

- `itertools.takewhile`:

  ```
  import itertools

  elegido = ["aaa", "bbb", "---", "ddd"]
  elegidos = tuple(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != "---", elegido))
  ```
- Un simple `for` que agregue los elementos a una lista:

  ```
  elegidos = []
  for e in elegido:
      if e == "---":
          break
      elegidos.append(v)
  ```
- `list.index` y slicing:

  ```
  try:
      i = elegido.index("---")
      elegidos = elegido[:i]
  except ValueError:
      elegidos = elegido
  ```

La lista elegidos se la puedes pasar sin problemas a `loc`.